# Javascript: final / immutable global variables?

Tags: javascript

I think I know the answer but... is there any way to prevent a global variable from being modified by later-executing `<script>`? I know global variables are bad in the first place, but when necessary, is there a way to make it "final" or "immutable"? Hacks / creative solutions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. But I'm sure there's a better solution, if you can say what kind of problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: just FYI, global variables are actually the properties of the window object and similary global functions are methods of the window object.

Answer (score 61):

the **[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Constants)** keyword?

Comment: why downvote? could you please give reason so that we know. I am not sure of my answer because I've never used it myself. So only I've put ques. mark in my answer. Moreover, when I tried in IE it failed. So, it'd be good if you clearify the reason for your downvote.

Comment: Not really sure why this got down voted, but this should work. At least, any browser that supports JS 1.5 or greater.

Comment: yeah, thats what was my initial idea for posting. but then again I wasn't totally sure because I hadn't used it myself.

Comment: @Presario. Its a standard in JS 1.5. Just because it doesn't work in Opera doesn't prove anything. It didn't work for me in IE6 too. And in my answer I am not claiming that its gonna work. I just quoted a hyperlink which I thought may be of some help. Do you see a '?' in my answer?

Comment: JavaScript is Mozilla's version of ECMAScript; if you want your scipt to work across different browsers, stick to what's in ECMA-262, 3rd edition

Comment: @Liverpool 4 - 1 Mancs. The question is not about standards, your suggestion/solution (whatever) does not work and therefore is of no use to the questioner. That's why it deserves a downvote.

Comment: [EWD about the distinction between language definition and implementation](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD04xx/EWD447.html)

Comment: It is not really supported. I once searched for hours when a page broke in IE because of that. **You should not use `const`!**

Comment: @RealRed. your answer after 6 years is starting to be relevant, but also is that const is not inmutable. check this answer about const http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/290514/57947

Comment: with const you can't do something like: const x; and at some point:  x = 12; so to make immutable after first initialization.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought `CONST` only meant that you couldn't redeclare the variable - it doens't make it immutable. e.g. you can still add items to the array using `push()` if the variable was declared as an array to start with, also using the `CONST` keyword. Again, I may have a core-misunderstanding here but this is just what I though was the case.

Answer (score 18):

I know this question is old, but you could use Object.freeze(yourGlobalObjectHere);
I just wrote a blog post about it [here](http://tripleequals.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-do-you-make-object-final-in.html).

Comment: Haven't tried it yet because I can't test it now. But seeing your description in your blog, I think this should be the correct answer. :) Because I want my global array to be immutable, so when I accidentally change it with some mutable function, it should warn/make an error.

Answer (score 15):

You can use closure technique, MYGLOBALS is an object that has a function called getValue against the "globals" associative array that is out of scope for everything except MYGLOBALS instance.

```
var MYGLOBALS = function() {
    var globals = {
        foo : "bar",
        batz : "blah"       
    }
    return { getValue : function(s) {
            return globals[s];
        }
    }
}();
alert(MYGLOBALS.getValue("foo"));  // returns "bar"
alert(MYGLOBALS.getValue("notthere")); // returns undefined
MYGLOBALS.globals["batz"] = 'hardeehar'; // this will throw an exception as it should
```

Comment: Nice try, but they can still replace the MYGLOBALS in one goal, anyway.

Comment: Or replace the `getValue` property in MYGLOBALS with another function that returns different values.

Comment: Forget about JavaScript, The truth is, There is nothing like immutable in this world. everything changes. Change is the constant :)

For JavaScript, we have to follow good practices and have knowledge of what we are doing.

Answer (score 9):

yes the const is short for constant or final in some languages. google "javascript variable const" or constant to double i have even tested it myself so

```
const yourVar = 'your value';
```

thats what you are looking for.

Comment: This won't work on Array or Dictionary. Using const will still allow you to add or remove elements from it.

Comment: @MichaelHarley Which is also the case in any other language when using final...

Answer (score 5):

This would be much cleaner approach

```
   var CONSTANTS = function() {
        var constants = { } ; //Initialize Global Space Here
        return {
            defineConstant: function(name,value)
            {
                if(constants[name])
                {
                   throw "Redeclaration of constant Not Allowed";
                }
            },
            getValue(name)
            {
               return constants[name];
            }
        } ;
    }() ;
    CONSTANTS.defineConstant('FOO','bar') ;
    console.log(CONSTANTS.getValue('FOO')) ; //Returns bar
    CONSTANTS.defineConstant('FOO','xyz') ; // throws exception as constant already defined
    CONSTANTS.getValue('XYZ') ; //returns undefined
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'CONSTANT_NAME', {value: CONSTANT_VALUE});

// usage
console.log(CONSTANT_NAME);
```

[`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) creates a property with the following default attributes:

- **`configurable`** true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
  **Defaults to false.**
- **`enumerable`** true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. **Defaults to false.**
- **`writable`** true if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator. **Defaults to false.**

if the "constant" is an object you might additionally want to make it immutable by freezing it. `obj =`[`Object.freeze(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). have in mind that child-property-objects are not automatically frozen.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
const whatEver = 'Hello World!!!';

function foo(value){
 whatEver = value;
}
```

then you would call it like so...

```
<div onclick="foo('New Value');">Change Me First</div>
<div onclick="alert(whatEver);">Then click me After: Should Be alert "Hello World!!!"</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Choose a variable name which is unlikely to be overwritten by accident and trust the programmer to not do stupid things. JavaScript is not Java, so don't pretend it was.

Also, if what you really want to do is namespacing, use a self-executing function literal:

```
var myLibName = (function() {
    var aPrivateVar;

    function aPrivateFunction() {}

    function accessorForPrivateVar() {
        return aPrivateVar;
    }

    // public interface:
    return {
        getPrivateVar : accessorForPrivateVar
    }
})();
```

Comment: Hi Christoph, before upvoting your solution, can you please elaborate a bit what self-execute function will do here? I have tried without self-execute function call then it throws an error like `Uncaught TypeError: myLibName.getPrivateVar is not a function`.

Answer (score 2):

what about this code by http://ejohn.org/ @ http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/

Look like this actually works... I run some "little" testing and freeze the variables and attributes.

> Freezing an object is the ultimate form of lock-down. Once an object
>   has been frozen it cannot be unfrozen – nor can it be tampered in any
>   manner. This is the best way to make sure that your objects will stay
>   exactly as you left them, indefinitely.

```
Object.freeze = function( obj ) {
  var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( obj );

  for ( var i = 0; i < props.length; i++ ) {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( obj, props[i] );

    if ( "value" in desc ) {
      desc.writable = false;
    }

    desc.configurable = false;
    Object.defineProperty( obj, props[i], desc );
  }

  return Object.preventExtensions( obj );
};
```

Little example

```
var config = (function (__name) {
    name: __name
    var _local = {
        Server: "SomeText",
        ServerDate: "SomeServerDate",
        JSDate : Util.today(),
        User : {
            user: "1stUser",
            name: "",
            email: ""
        },        
    }

    /*Private Methods*/
    function freezing(__array) {
        $.each(__array, function (_index, _item) {
            Object.freeze(_item);
        });
    }

    /*Public Methods*/
    var $r = {};

    $r.info = function () {
        return _local;
    }

    freezing([
        _local,
        _local.User
    ]);


    _local.User.user = "newUser"; //Trying to assing new value

    //Remain with the same value as first declaration
    console.log(_local.User.user); //--> "1stUser"           
    return $r;
})("config");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Conventions and good Documentation.**

You can prefix your "immutable" variable with two (or more) underscores to indicate that is something not meant to be used by others and to avoid other people's variables clashing with yours.

Maybe creating a 'namespace' like `__GLOBALNAMESPACE` (Ugly name, I know) and then adding your variables into it (eg `__GLOBALNAMESPACE.my_var`) and creating a method like this one to retrieve them:

```
getVariable(string name){
  return __GLOBALNAMESPACE[name]
}
```

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring all such variables in the global scope, you could have one global object wrapping around those variables. Using `Object.defineProperty()` and/or `Object.defineProperties()` with the `writable` flag set to `false`, you can have an immutable variable.

```
var myObj = {};

Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'myVar', {
    value: someValue,
    writable: false
});
```

Or you could just use the [const keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

```
const MY_VAR = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out this [jquery plugin](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/hide-javascript-global-objects-with-jquery-secret-plugin/). It prevents you to create global objects in javascript :)

#### example code

Store data

```
// 'val' can be a string, integer, hash table, array, object
$.secret( 'in', 'secretName', val );

// or a function
$.secret( 'in', 'secretName', function( arg1, arg2, arg3 ){
  // do something here
});
```

Use data; you can even use it in different files.

```
var lang = $.secret( 'out', 'lang' );
```

Call out a function

```
$.secret( 'call', 'secretName', [ arg1, arg2, arg3 ]);
// or
$.secret( 'call', 'secretName', arg );
```

Clear data

```
$.secret( 'clear', 'lang' );
```

source code is on [github](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.secret)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is object oriented, rather than making the variable *$public static*, consider making it private and then properly providing an acessor method for getting, but not setting it.

e.g.

```
private var myGlobal : myType;
function GetMyGlobal() : myType
{
return myGlobal;
}
```

> There are ten different ways to solve any given problem, your way and the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use typescript, you can mark properties as `readonly`

Answer (score 0):

The following example code makes a **globally** available variable **immutable**

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, `env`, {
    value: Object.freeze({
        API: "https://api.mywebsite.com",
    }),
});
```

And it can be referenced from either `window.env` or just `env`.